# Link error: "relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: c++, cmake, fpic

I am trying to build a shared library using Cmake. But I facing this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(assert.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried to add -fPIC flag to cmake file in different ways as:

```
SET(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

and:

```
add_compile_options(-fPIC)
```

But I still get same error again. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(assert.o)` - this suggests that the `-fPIC` issue is not related to the library you are building, but instead the one that you are linking against. You could try building `/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a` with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Thank @lubgr! it's works for me! I recompile the troublesome library again with -fPIC flag.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by [@lubgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9593596/lubgr) and confirmed by [@Fayyaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8486529/fayyaz) in the comments, the specific problem here was due to the library being linked against needing to be recompiled with the `-fPIC` flag- not the target linking to that library.